# Giving attributes to physical domains in gmsh

Tags: mesh

Based on my previous question [physical entities for gmsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824987/gmsh-issue-with-physical-entities) I am moving forward trying to understand if it is possible to give domain characteristics to the physical entities defined in the `*.geo` file.

I am developing a FEM code, and in this case I am trying to define everything in the mesh file, I mean: domains, boundaries, properties of domains, etc, everything that involves problem settings. See the following `*.geo` file:

```
Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, 1.0};
Point(2) = {1, 0, 0, 1.0};
Point(3) = {1, 1, 0, 1.0};
Point(4) = {0, 1, 0, 1.0};
Point(5) = {0, 0.5, 0, 1.0};
Point(6) = {1, 0.5, 0, 1.0};
Line(1) = {1, 2};
Line(2) = {2, 6};
Line(3) = {6, 3};
Line(4) = {3, 4};
Line(5) = {4, 5};
Line(6) = {5, 1};
Line(7) = {5, 6};
Line Loop(8) = {4, 5, 7, 3};
Plane Surface(9) = {8};
Line Loop(10) = {7, -2, -1, -6};
Plane Surface(11) = {10};
Physical Surface('top') = {9};
Physical Surface('bottom') = {11};
```

It is my intention to write in the `*.geo` file the aforementioned definitions. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, [you should not](http://gmsh.info//doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Mesh-module-questions) (look at question 13 in this section of GMSH FAQ). According to GMSH philosophy,  and

> this job is best left to the solver, GMSH provides a simple mechanism to tag groups of elements

– which you are already using.

The long version:

I guess, the intention is to use `*.msh` file (obtained by GMSH processing the corresponding `*.geo` file) as an input to the FEM solver. Thus, we can use the specification of [GMSH *.msh](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#MSH-file-format-_0028version-4_0029). (As GMSH just recently updated to v4, we can also look at the previous [legacy MSH v2](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#MSH-file-format-version-2)).

In v4 (v2 offers even less), the following sections are available (some, optional):

1. `MeshFormat` – header info
2. `PhysicalNames` - the connection between physical groups numbers and names
3. `Entities`, `Partitioned Entities`, `Nodes`, `Elements`, `GhostElements` – geometry definitions
4. `Periodic` – info on the periodicity
5. `NodeData`, `ElementData`, `ElementNodeData` - **postprocessing**-intent datasets.

So, there is not a section that will naturally fit your needs.
You are left with two **bad** choices (the ones that I can come up with):

- Since sections with unknown headers are ignored, you can manually (after `*.msh` is generated) add your data there and provide your solver with the required input functionality based on your needs
- try using postprocessing-intent `ElementData`, but that renders the use of Physical Group tags useless (as you'll have to do it based on individual element IDs)

So, based on that, I would stop at properly assigning physical group tags and numbers and do the material properties assignment on the side of your FEM solver.

Comment: Thank you for the patience. Your answers are really helpful.